# Parse string from URL and store in variable?

Tags: php, string, parsing, url, youtube-api

I send a query to youtube api to get an access token to allow users of my applicaton to upload videos, edit meta data and delete videos as they please. I am able to send the request and have the user grant youtube api access. The one problem I am running in to, and have not been able to find a way around, is the access token is appended to the URL after the redirect is made. So for example the URL in my browser after granting youtube access is

'http://www.mysite.com/path/to/web/application/#access_token=a-very-long-string-that-is-the-access-token-this-is-what-i-need&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600'

I have been reading up on parse_str and parse_url, but I am no php master so do not know how to use them properly. I'm not even sure this can be done, but I need to store the access token in a variable so I can use it again.

Answer (score 1):

The hash value doesn't get sent to the server and there's no way to retreive it using PHP alone.

But you can use JavaScript to get the anchor part of the URL:

```
var query = location.href.split("#")
hashPart = query[1];
```

The anchor part is now stored in `hashPart` variable. Now you can simply send an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to a PHP file on your server.

And in PHP, you can retrieve it like so:

```
$token = $_GET['foo'];
// do stuff ...
```

Comment: If I alert hashPart, it seems to just return everything but the part i need

Comment: var query = location.href.split("#")
hashPart1 = query[0];
hashPart2 = query[1]; The part after "#" is in the second row of the array. In hashPart2. (In query[1])